# HTML/CSS - How to set text (e.g. 'Quote of the Day') to change automatically on page load/reload?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am quite new to HTML/CSS. I've got a fairly basic website going in which I have a funny quote under my title. My friend asked me if it changes every time the page loads and that gave me the idea to do something like that. I was wondering if there was any way to manage this in HTML/CSS. I do know some Javascript, so I can also do it on that if needed.

Do I need a list of quotes saved in a file? Can they be pulled from a website/online list? What is the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What have you researched so far?

Comment: I tried saving about 10 quotes in a JS and using a Math.random pull one and place it in the HTML document.

Comment: @SukhyGills what was wrong with the JS `Math.random` solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get an idea of ways to improve your question and get better answers.

Comment: @Hugo After reviewing the code David has posted, I believe the issue was with 

var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)

I had missed the Math.floor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Math.random()` to get your randomized index. `Math.random()` generates a value from 0 (inclusive) to 1 (exclusive).

The `onload` will be called each time the page is loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="randomQuotes()">

    <h1>Hello World!</h1>

    <p id="quote"></p>

    <script>
    var quotes = ['hi', 'bye', 'lol', 'hello', 'world']
    function randomQuotes() {
        var idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)
        document.getElementById('quote').innerHTML = quotes[idx]
    }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I compared your code to mine, and I had just missed the Math.floor function.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free Quote and Expression API called [Forismatic](http://forismatic.com/en/api/) which retrieves a random inspiring quote or expressions. [See here for an example quote](http://forismatic.com/en/#cdde4a8f41/).

I created an example Codepen of this API using JQuery with AJAX and Bootstrap:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        var quote = $('.quote-text');
        getQuote(quote);
        $('#getQuote').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            getQuote(quote);
        });
    });

    function getQuote(quote) {
        var url = 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            quote.html(data.quoteText);
        });
    }
</script>

<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <p class="quote-text"></p>
    <button id="getQuote" class="btn">Get Quote</button>
</div>
```

You can see the codepen here - http://codepen.io/jamesg1/pen/zKORbk

Comment: I think this is something I can use if I can find a website to match the theme of website (Comic/Funny). Thank you.

Comment: @SukhyGills To use this code you also could consume a JSON object with  your own quote. Adding to this example the author and year could be added.

Comment: I hadn't considered that. The website was an assignment, which has since been submitted. However, I will definitely consider this for the next one I make. It will be very useful, thank you.